# What Tags to Choose

Tags: discussion, tags

I was about to ask a beginner question on getting started with home recording. Can someone suggest a set of tags that may be useful to me and others? If this should have been asked on meta site, please feel free to move it over :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://audio.stackexchange.com/tags
I'd say "home-studio" would be enough.
The meta-tag "beginner" is deemed [inappropriate](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) :)

Comment: Thanks Jan - that answers it :-)

Answer (score 4):

My advise would be that if you're in doubt  ask it anyway and add whichever tags you feel are appropriate. Other users can always retag your questions.